# pkgProblemResolver error when running apt --fix-broken install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to run an `apt upgrade`, but it is requiring me to run `apt --fix-broken install` first. However, when I run that command, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1 : Breaks: libc6 (< 2.29-4) but 2.27-3 is installed
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
                  Breaks: libc6 (< 2.29-4) but 2.27-3 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.29)
           Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is installed
 locales-all : Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

For whatever reason, I cannot seem to get rid of this error. I've tried to remove the packages mentioned in this output, but no luck as they require me to run `apt --fix-broken install` yet again.

***Attempt #1***

Saw this post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918366/error-pkgproblemresolver. However, when running:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

there is no output, indicating there is no line containing the word "hold". I also tried the second suggestion in top answer, which is to install aptititude using `sudo apt-get install aptitude`; However, when running this, this also doesn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.67.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.1.0-5 is to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but 1.4.5-1 is to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt1 : Breaks: libc6 (< 2.29-4) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
                  Breaks: libc6 (< 2.29-4) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.29)
           Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales-all : Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

***Attempt #2***

I also tried to just simply remove libcrypt1, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/633544/e-error-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-he referring to the OP's error, but that didn't work and provided me with the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
                  Breaks: libc6 (< 2.29-4) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.29)
           Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
 locales-all : Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.29) but 2.27-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

There is also nothing in the `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file (it doesn't exist). My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file only contains a single line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Something is terribly screwed up and I have no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel

After running `dpkg -l | grep ^iU | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge`, I was able to continue with `apt upgrade`

Comment: i tried above link,
but running both of your codes that solved my issue.